# ffmpeg - video conversion with multiple audio tracks

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting an mkv h.264 video to HEVC. The file has two audio tracks. How can I copy all audio tracks?

I used this command (from a `.bat` file):

```
ffmpeg -i "!original!" -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -c:a copy "g:\Prepare\Convert\!file!"
```

This exports only one audio track, but I always I need to copy all audio tracks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "!original!" \
    -map 0:v \
    -map 0:a \
    -c:v libx265 \
    -preset medium \
    -crf 28 \
    -c:a copy \
    "g:\Prepare\Convert\!file!"
```

FFmpeg by default only picks one video, audio and subtitle track (if they are present) from among the sources. Express map assignments are required in order to include other streams. `0:a` selects all audio streams.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that using -map 0 will select *all* tracks, including subtitles if available.

```
ffmpeg -i "!original!" -map 0 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -c:a copy "g:\Prepare\Convert\!file!"
```

Comment: Saved my day !!